# Why the line of intersection of two planes containing 1 line each would intersect the two Lines as well?

Tags: vectors, 3d

Consider Line $L_1$ and let a plane containing it be $P_1$, Similarly consider Line $L_2$ and let a plane containing it be $P_2$. If $P_1$ and $P_2$ intersect and make line $L_3$, I don't understand how the line $L_3$ would intersect $L_1$ and $L_2$ as well.
Is this always true?
Or is it true for the condition that the normals of $P_1$ and $P_2$ are perpendicular to another given line $L_4$

Comment: What if the lines are all parallel?

Comment: $L_1$ and $L_3$ are both lines in $P_1$. Therefore they either intersect or are parallel. The same goes for $L_2$ and $L_3$ in $P_2$. (Note: You refer to $L_1$ (respectively, $L_2$) and *the* plane containing it being $P_1$ (respectively, $P_2$). There isn't a unique plane containing any line, but I imagine this is just ambiguous wording.)

Comment: No, it isn't always true.  You could have $L_3$ parallel to $L_1$ or parallel to $L_2$ are parallel to both, or intersect on and parallel to the other or intersect both.  But $L_3$ as Briang Tung points out must intersect or be parallel to those lines.

Comment: thank you, i have understood

Answer (score 0):

If two planes $P_1, P_2$ are not identical and are not parallel to each other then they intersect and the points that lie in the intersection of $P_1, P_2$ is  described by a line, $L_{1,2}$.

**Case (1):** Let a line $L_{a} \in P_1$ intersect $L_{1,2}$ at $A(x_0, y_0)$ and
another line $L_{b} \in P_2$ intersect $L_{1,2}$ at $B(x_1, y_1)$. By definition,  $L_{1,2}$ is the unique line passing through the two points $A,B$.

**Case (2):** Let $L_{a} \in P_1$ be parallel to $L_{1,2}$ **or** $L_{b} \in P_2$ be parallel to $L_{1,2}$. Then $L_{a}$ and $L_{b}$ do not intersect each other.